# Problema al Obtener datos con Datatable jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, datatable

Gracias por la atención de antemano, les explico un poco mi situación, soy nuevo en Php y jQuery, MySQL me di cuenta que existe un plugin llamado Data table que es muy practico, efectivamente me ha funcionado mucho al punto que estoy haciendo un CRUD usando el data table para obtener los datos, agregar datos y  editarlos , cuando se carga el datatable obtengo el id del row y obtengo los datos de los campos para editarlos ahora cuando el id es básico de tipo Sting aunque carácter numérico '01' o '1 'el botón obtiene bien el índice que indica el data table y jala bien la información.

pero cuando el ID es compuesto por ejemplo xxd-k01-21 no logro que el botón funcione, alguno sabe por que este problema y por donde podría comenzar a solucionar esta situación, gracias

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Una actualización del estado de mi consulta, ya logre solucionar la situación de las comillas en el botón utilizando ' ' en el botón de esta manera onclick="EditarProducto(''.$data[$i]['id_producto'].'') ya que el anterior no tenia y por ello solo pasaba el dato sin formato Sting, aunque sigo sin poder solucionar el problema de la obtención de datos mediante un ID compuesto con guion

Comment: Bienvenido, Gabriel. No conozco este plugin, pero por regla general, los datos en las bases de datos tienen asignado un "tipo de datos" por cada campo o columna. De acuerdo a lo que nos dices, este campo "id" es tipo string (texto), y en ese sentido, tu plugin debiera reconocer eso. Fíjate si existe alguna configuración previa en tu plugin, donde le especifiques el "tipo de dato" a ese campo, de modo que sea del mismo tipo que el que viene de la base, para que sea congruente. Además, es probable que actualmente tu plugin tome los guiones como separador de columnas o algo así... Suerte.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, efectivamente, pude comprobar que estoy obteniendo solo una parte del ID por ejemplo si es  xxd-k01 solo la parte de K01 pero tengo o problema y es en el botón editar, ejemplo, en la propiedad onclick=Editar('.envio el ID.') , si embargo en el navegador puedo ver que el ID en la propiedad onclick no tiene la comilla simple ejemplo <button class="btn-sm btn-info mb-2" type="button" onclick="Editar(A19);">y por ello no jala la data ya que en la BD debe contener las comillas para hacer la consulta, como podría pasar el ID con todo y las comillas?? gracias de antemano

Comment: logre solucionar el problema, tenia un fallo de novato a la hora de hacer la consulta en el modelo ya que cuando hago la sentencia a la Base de datos no agrego 'comillas' al parámetro, dando así por concluido los dos problemas que tenia básicamente en los dos casos era un problema de comillas simples, agradezco la colaboración  en éste caso muchas gracias